# Flash AS3 - Posting XMLList Value in text area using htmltext

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Creating an RSS reader. One feature is that should parse several "category" nodes from a feed. But when I load a feed, the category doesn't shows up in the text area. Flash returns no errors.

Heres the code -

```
var curStory = rssXML.channel.item[evt.target.selectedIndex]
var  catlist:XMLList  =  curStory.category;
taLog.htmlText =   curStory.description + catlist[1];
```

Note - `curStory.description` parses fine without `catlist[1]`, and trace returns the value I want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing on namespaces.

```
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var curStory = rssXML.ns::channel.ns::item[evt.target.selectedIndex]
var  catlist:XMLList  =  curStory.ns::category;
taLog.htmlText =   curStory.ns::description + catlist[1];
```

Or you can use the `default xml namespace` and continue with the existing code:

```
default xml namespace = new Namespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
var curStory = rssXML.channel.item[evt.target.selectedIndex]
var  catlist:XMLList  =  curStory.category;
taLog.htmlText =   curStory.description + catlist[1];
```